# Highlight column and row in a table ::after and ::before not work

Tags: html, css

When the mouse is on a cell, I want to highlight the corresponding column and row. And I also want to highlight the row when the mouse on the letter of the player 1's action, and highlight the column when the mouse on the letter of player 2's action.

This is the code I tried:

```css
th {
  font-weight: normal;
  align-content: center;
}

td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1.1cm;
  width: 1.1cm;
}

.col {
  width: 1.1cm;
}

.row {
  height: 1.1cm;
}

.rotate {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1.5em;
}

.rotate div {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* FF3.5+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
  /* IE6,IE7 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
  /* IE8 */
  margin-left: -0.5cm;
  margin-right: -0.5cm;
}

.float-left {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

tr.hl:hover th:not([rowspan]),
tr.hl:hover td {
  background-color: yellow;
}

td:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

td:hover::after,
.col:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="player1">

  <tr style="color: red">
    <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right">Player 1's Payoffs </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2 rowspan=2></th>
    <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 2's actions</th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <th class="col">d</th>
    <th class="col">e</th>
    <th class="col">f</th>
  </tr>


  <tr style="color: red" class="hl">
    <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller;">
      <div>Player 1's actions</div>
    </th>
    <th class="row">a</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="color: red" class="hl">
    <th class="row">b</th>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: red" class="hl">
    <th class="row">c</th>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Currently I can get the row highlighted, but not the column.
I am wondering how I can do it in CSS. Or some other ways.

Comment: you'll need some `JavaScript` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give a width and increase height and overflow what might overflows.

possible approach

```css
.rotate {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;
  /* if understood */
}

th {
  font-weight: normal;
  align-content: center;
}

td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1.1cm;
  width: 1.1cm;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px white;
}

.col {
  width: 1.1cm;
}

.row {
  height: 1.1cm;
}

.rotate {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1.5em;
}

.float-left {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

tr.hl:hover th:not([rowspan]),
tr.hl:hover td {
  background-color: yellow;
}

td:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

td:hover::after,
.col:hover::after {
  content: 'j';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 2000%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -1000%;
  left: 0;
}

th,
td {
  position: relative;
}

#player1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

thead th {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white;
}
```

```html
<table id="player1">
  <thead>
    <tr style="color: red">
      <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right">Player 1's Payoffs </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=2></th>
      <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 2's actions</th>
    </tr>


  </thead>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <th colspan=2></th>
    <th class="col">d</th>
    <th class="col">e</th>
    <th class="col">f</th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="color: red" class="hl">
    <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller;">
      <div>Player 1's actions</div>
    </th>
    <th class="row">a</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="color: red" class="hl">
    <th class="row">b</th>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: red" class="hl">
    <th class="row">c</th>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Hi, it looks good in snippet. but it does not hightlight the d/e/f. Actually it gives me similar result as before in my brower. Hidden overflow makes the rightmost line dissapears. I use chrome. does it actually affect the results？

Comment: @Jasmin I updated the snippet to exclude  d/e/f from the header part . you have the essential part to make it work,

Comment: works! a follow-up question. How do I fixed the disappeared line? I set td border 2px, but it does not look good. Actually I have 4 such tables side by side in one line.