# CSS Highlighting table row and column is not effective

Tags: css

I have 4 tables side by side like the one in [Highlight column and row in a table ::after and ::before not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639403/highlight-column-and-row-in-a-table-after-and-before-not-work)

My problem is that, take the table in that question for example, when the mouse goes from c to b or a (or from b to a) the highlight stays at the row with c instead of moving to b or a (stays at the row with b). Basically, it works fine when the mouse goes from upside to downside, but not from downside to the upside.

I am wondering how to fix it. Because I also make the table cell highlighted when it is clicked, and record which cell is highlighted and unhighlighted, so the problem somtimes makes a wrong cell highlighted when clicked, and makes the record somehow biased.

I am testing using Chrome.

Here is an example

```css
            th{
                font-weight: normal;
                align-content: center;
            }
            td {
                border: black solid;
                border-width: 1px 2px 1px 1px;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                height:1.1cm;
                width:1.1cm;
                background-clip: padding-box

            }
            .col {
                width: 1.1cm;
            }
            .rotate {
                text-align: center;
                white-space: nowrap;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                width: 1.5em;
                }
            .rotate div {
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
                -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
                filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /* IE6,IE7 */
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
                margin-left: -1cm;
                margin-right: -1cm;
                }
            .float-left {
                width: 25%;
                float: left;
            }
            tr.hl:hover th:not([rowspan]),
            tr.hl:hover td {
                background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.25);
            }
            td:hover::before {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.25);
                z-index: 0;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0;
            }
            td:hover::after,
            .col:hover::after {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.25);
                z-index: 0;
                height: 2000%;
                width: 100%;
                bottom: -1000%;
                left: 0;
            }
            th,
            td {
                position: relative;
            }
            table{
                overflow: hidden;

            }
            thead th{
                background-color:white;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white;
                z-index: 1;
            }
```

```html
<div class="g1g2">
        <div class="float-left">
            <table id="player1" style="margin-bottom: 1cm">
             <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right" >Player 1's Payoffs </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=2 rowspan=2></th>
            <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 2's actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
             <th colspan="2"></th>
            <th class="col">d</th>
            <th class="col">e</th>
            <th class="col">f</th>
        </tr>


        <tr class="hl">
            <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller;"> <div>Player 1's actions</div></th>
            <th>a</th>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="hl">
            <th>b</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>c</th>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="g1g2">
             <div class="float-left">
         <table id="player2" style="margin-bottom: 1cm">
             <thead>
             <tr>
            <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right">Player 2's Payoffs </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=2 rowspan=2></th>
            <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 3's actions</th>
        </tr>
             </thead>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
             <th colspan="2"></th>
            <th class="col">g</th>
            <th class="col">h</th>
            <th class="col">i</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller"> <div>Player 2's actions</div></th>
            <th>d</th>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>e</th>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>f</th>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
    </div>


    <div class="g1g2">
        <div class="float-left">
         <table id="player3" style="margin-bottom: 1cm">
             <thead>
             <tr>
                <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right">Player 3's Payoffs </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=2 rowspan=2></th>
                <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 4's actions</th>
            </tr>
             </thead>
             <tr style="text-align: center">
                  <th colspan="2"></th>
                <th class="col">j</th>
                <th class="col">k</th>
                <th class="col">l</th>
            </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller"> <div>Player 3's actions</div></th>
            <th>g</th>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>h</th>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>i</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="g1">
<div class="float-left">
         <table id="player4a" style="margin-bottom: 1cm">
              <thead>
             <tr>
                <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right">Player 4's Payoffs </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=2 rowspan=2></th>
                <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 1's actions</th>
            </tr>
             </thead>
            <tr style="text-align: center">
                 <th colspan="2"></th>
                <th class="col">a</th>
                <th class="col">b</th>
                <th class="col">c</th>
            </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller"> <div>Player 4's actions</div></th>
            <th>j</th>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>k</th>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>l</th>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
         </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should post your example here. I can not reproduce your issue from the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest fix would be to add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to `::after` and `::before` pseudo elements. [It also has a great browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events).

Tbh I haven't looked at the code xD, but probably another fix would to be to mess around with `z-index` which I won't recommend since it can be solved with `pointer-events`.

```css
            th{
                font-weight: normal;
                align-content: center;
            }
            td {
                border: black solid;
                border-width: 1px 2px 1px 1px;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                height:1.1cm;
                width:1.1cm;
                background-clip: padding-box

            }
            .col {
                width: 1.1cm;
            }
            .rotate {
                text-align: center;
                white-space: nowrap;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                width: 1.5em;
                }
            .rotate div {
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
                -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
                filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /* IE6,IE7 */
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
                margin-left: -1cm;
                margin-right: -1cm;
                }
            .float-left {
                width: 25%;
                float: left;
            }
            tr.hl:hover th:not([rowspan]),
            tr.hl:hover td {
                background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.25);
            }
            td:hover::before {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.25);
                z-index: 0;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0;
            }
            td:hover::after,
            .col:hover::after {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.25);
                z-index: 0;
                height: 2000%;
                width: 100%;
                bottom: -1000%;
                left: 0;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            th,
            td {
                position: relative;
            }
            table{
                overflow: hidden;

            }
            thead th{
                background-color:white;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white;
                z-index: 1;
            }
```

```html
<div class="g1g2">
        <div class="float-left">
            <table id="player1" style="margin-bottom: 1cm">
             <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right" >Player 1's Payoffs </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=2 rowspan=2></th>
            <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 2's actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
             <th colspan="2"></th>
            <th class="col">d</th>
            <th class="col">e</th>
            <th class="col">f</th>
        </tr>


        <tr class="hl">
            <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller;"> <div>Player 1's actions</div></th>
            <th>a</th>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="hl">
            <th>b</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>c</th>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="g1g2">
             <div class="float-left">
         <table id="player2" style="margin-bottom: 1cm">
             <thead>
             <tr>
            <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right">Player 2's Payoffs </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=2 rowspan=2></th>
            <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 3's actions</th>
        </tr>
             </thead>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
             <th colspan="2"></th>
            <th class="col">g</th>
            <th class="col">h</th>
            <th class="col">i</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller"> <div>Player 2's actions</div></th>
            <th>d</th>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>e</th>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>f</th>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
    </div>


    <div class="g1g2">
        <div class="float-left">
         <table id="player3" style="margin-bottom: 1cm">
             <thead>
             <tr>
                <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right">Player 3's Payoffs </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=2 rowspan=2></th>
                <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 4's actions</th>
            </tr>
             </thead>
             <tr style="text-align: center">
                  <th colspan="2"></th>
                <th class="col">j</th>
                <th class="col">k</th>
                <th class="col">l</th>
            </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller"> <div>Player 3's actions</div></th>
            <th>g</th>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>h</th>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>i</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="g1">
<div class="float-left">
         <table id="player4a" style="margin-bottom: 1cm">
              <thead>
             <tr>
                <th colspan=5 style="text-align: right">Player 4's Payoffs </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=2 rowspan=2></th>
                <th colspan=3 style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center">Player 1's actions</th>
            </tr>
             </thead>
            <tr style="text-align: center">
                 <th colspan="2"></th>
                <th class="col">a</th>
                <th class="col">b</th>
                <th class="col">c</th>
            </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th rowspan=3 class="rotate" style="font-size: smaller"> <div>Player 4's actions</div></th>
            <th>j</th>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>k</th>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hl">
            <th>l</th>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
         </table>
</div>
</div>
```