# How to randomly match players into groups

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 4-player (p1, p2, p3, p4) game like this: [CSS Highlighting table row and column is not effective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937149/css-highlighting-table-row-and-column-is-not-effective)

I have two such games g1 and g2, and a number of subjects N who will play the two games as each Player for a total of 8 rounds. They will face a fixed order of the games (e.g., g1p3, g2p2, g1p2, g2p1, g2p3, g1p1, g2p4, g1p4). Their payoff depends on the actions they choose.

Ideally, in each round, subjects will be randomly matched into a group of 4 to play the game, and these 4 subjects are randomly assigned a role. Say I have 8 subjects who are randomly divided into 2 groups in the first round. In each group, say subject1 is randomly assigned to be Player1, subject2 is randomly assigned to be player2 and so on. Then after they finish this round, I can know their payoffs based on the actions they choose. Then similar procedure for the next round but I just rematch the groups. However, in my design, in each round, every subjects is assigned to the same role because of the fixed order of the games that every subject is facing, I cannot do the above match, so I have to match subjects after they all finish 8 rounds.

I have one idea of how to do it:

1. I get all the subjects
2. random.shuffle subjects and get the first 4 subjects `swap = [a, b, c, d]`.
3. divide them into groups:

```
        i = 0
        while i <= 3:
            groups = [players[x:x+4] for x in range(0, num_players, 4)]
            players.remove(swap[i])
            players.append(swap[i])
            i += 1
            for x in groups:
                group = x
                print('group', group)
                player_1 = group[0]
                player_2 = group[1]
                player_3 = group[2]
                player_4 = group[3]
                action1 = player_1.in_round(6).submitted_answer #get player's action when he is player 1 which is in round 6
                action2 = player_2.in_round(3).submitted_answer #get player's action when he is player 2 which is in round 3
                action3 = player_3.in_round(1).submitted_answer #get player's action when he is player 3 which is in round 1
                action4 = player_4.in_round(8).submitted_answer #get player's action when he is player 4 which is in round 8
                #code to determin the payoff based on the actions...
```

This is the output of the above code in an example of 8 subjects. Here for example, in the first row player 3 is in the role of Player 1, Player 8 is in the role of Player 2, player 5 is in the role of Player 3, player 6 is in the role of Player 4. In this example, player 3 appear 4 times, and each time he is in a different role. Same for the other players. This feature is what I need.

```
group [<Player  3>, <Player  8>, <Player  5>, <Player  6>]
group [<Player  4>, <Player  2>, <Player  7>, <Player  1>]
group [<Player  8>, <Player  5>, <Player  6>, <Player  4>]
group [<Player  2>, <Player  7>, <Player  1>, <Player  3>]
group [<Player  5>, <Player  6>, <Player  4>, <Player  2>]
group [<Player  7>, <Player  1>, <Player  3>, <Player  8>]
group [<Player  6>, <Player  4>, <Player  2>, <Player  7>]
group [<Player  1>, <Player  3>, <Player  8>, <Player  5>]
```

The problem is that this is not really random match apart from the first match, since after first match the order of players just shifts a bit. What I want is every match is as random as possible and they are matched in a way that their payoffs in every round can be determined.

**Edit with Solutions** not efficient though

```
import random
import itertools
import pprint

players = list(range(1,9))
num_groups = int(len(players)/4)


random.shuffle(players)
groups_round1 = [players[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(players), 4)]
print('round1', groups_round1)
position_round1 = []
positions_round1 = {}
for k in players:
  position_round1 = [ x.index(k) for x in groups_round1 if k in x]
  positions_round1[k] = position_round1
all_groups={'round1': groups_round1}

i=2
while i <= 4:
  finish1 = False
  round_num = 'round' + str(i)
  all_groups[round_num]=[]
  while finish1 == False:
    random.shuffle(players)
    groups_base = [players[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(players), 4)]
    possible_groups = [list(itertools.permutations(g)) for g in groups_base] 
    groups = []
    positions = {}
    positions[round_num] = {}
    a = 1
    for x in possible_groups:
      group = 'group' + str(a)
      positions[round_num][group]={}
      for y in x:
        for k in players:
          if k in y:
            position = [y.index(k)]
            positions[round_num][group][k] = position
        check = []
        for key in positions[round_num][group].keys():
          if i == 2:
            if positions[round_num][group].get(key, None) == positions_round1.get(key, None):
              break
            else:
              check.append('pass')
          elif i == 3:
            if positions[round_num][group].get(key, None) == positions_round1.get(key, None) \
            or positions[round_num][group].get(key, None) == positions_round2.get(key, None):
              break
            else:
              check.append('pass')
          elif i == 4:
              if positions[round_num][group].get(key, None) == positions_round1.get(key, None) \
              or positions[round_num][group].get(key, None) == positions_round2.get(key, None)\
              or positions[round_num][group].get(key, None) == positions_round3.get(key, None):
                  break
              else:
                  check.append('pass')
        condition = ['pass']*4
        if check == condition:
            groups.append(list(y))
            if i == 2:
                positions_round2={}
                for k in players:
                    position_round2 = [ x.index(k) for x in groups if k in x]
                    positions_round2[k] = position_round2
            elif i == 3:
                positions_round3={}
                for k in players:
                    position_round3 = [x.index(k) for x in groups if k in x]
                    positions_round3[k] = position_round3
            elif i == 4:
                positions_round4={}
                for k in players:
                    position_round4 = [x.index(k) for x in groups if k in x]
                    positions_round4[k] = position_round4
            all_groups[round_num]=groups
            break
      a += 1
    if int(len(groups)) == num_groups:
      finish1 = True
  print(round_num,groups)
  i += 1
```

with sample output:

```
round1 [[7, 8, 4, 2], [1, 3, 6, 5]]
round2 [[2, 5, 3, 1], [8, 6, 7, 4]]
round3 [[4, 1, 5, 7], [6, 2, 8, 3]]
round4 [[5, 7, 2, 6], [3, 4, 1, 8]]
```

Comment: Could you add a valid Python input and the corresponding output (as an example)? Is not clear, at least to me, from the description of the question what do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) in order to randomize the overall order of players and then assign groups in order (i.e. players at positions 1 to 4 go to group 1, the ones at 5 to 8 go to group 2, etc). Then within each group you can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to generate the role assignments. In order to randomize these you can use `random.shuffle` again. Here is some example code:

```
import itertools as it
import pprint
import random

N = 8
players = list(range(N))  # Players are identified by their integer id.

random.shuffle(players)  # Groups will be assigned in order, so shuffle beforehand.
groups = zip(*[iter(players)]*4)  # Group into 4-tuples.
groups = [list(it.permutations(g)) for g in groups]  # Assign roles within group.
for g in groups:
    random.shuffle(g)  # Shuffle the order of role assignment.

pprint.pprint(groups[0])  # For example group 1.
```

#### In case groups are reassigned every round

Here we can use only `random.shuffle` since groups and positions are assigned in order, so if the order of players is shuffled both groups and positions are randomized:

```
import itertools as it
import pprint
import random

N = 8
players = list(range(N))  # Players are identified by their integer id.

groupings = []
for __ in range(5):  # Playing 5 rounds.
    random.shuffle(players)  # Groups and positions will be assigned in order, so shuffle beforehand.
    groupings.append(tuple(zip(*[iter(players)]*4)))  # Group into 4-tuples.

pprint.pprint(groupings)
```

with the sample output:

```
[((5, 6, 7, 2), (4, 0, 3, 1)),
 ((7, 4, 2, 6), (0, 3, 5, 1)),
 ((2, 6, 1, 7), (4, 3, 0, 5)),
 ((5, 6, 1, 4), (2, 7, 0, 3)),
 ((4, 5, 2, 3), (6, 7, 0, 1))]
```

Comment: but the members in a group is fixed. I want changes in members in a group as well.

Comment: @Jasmin Sure, every time you `shuffle` and reassign groups this will change. So you just need to put that into another loop. Or do you want to run only with one configuration and then regroup all players? Then you can just use shuffle and group/role assignment based on position.

Comment: sure, but it does not ensure that every player will be in a different position when he is in a new group if put it into another loop, does it?

Comment: @Jasmin It does ensure randomized positions as well, since both groups *and* positions are assigned by order, and if that order is shuffled both is randomized. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Got it. in your sample output, for example, 1 is in position 4 for 3 times. If I want to make 1 shows in different positions each time without repetition in, say 4 rounds, 1 in position 1, in position 3, in position 4 and in position 2 each time 1 is assigned into a group, I am thinking to use while loop, until the above condition is satisfied, it could be time consuming though.

Comment: @Jasmin So you want to randomize group and positions assignment while ensuring that each player does not repeat a position? Does the same hold for the groups? I.e. can a player be assigned the same group multiple times?

Comment: Yes,  so a player can be in the same group but he need to be in a different position.

Comment: @Jasmin What if that is not possible? Assume there are 16 players and the groups are randomly assigned as follows: `g1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]; g2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]; g3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]; g4 = [13, 14, 15, 16]` and then in the next round the following assignment happens: `g1 = {1, 5, 9, 13}; ...`. Here all four players `1, 5, 9, 13` have been in position 1 already so one of them needs to repeat that position. Should the algorithm also prevent such cases or it doesn't matter if it's not possible to assign a different position within a group?

Comment: I wish that this case can be avoided for every four rounds because of 4 positions in one game. Say for the second set of four rounds, within these four rounds, I want no repetition, but across the first and second sets of 4 rounds, there can be repetition. I edit with my current solutions, which is not efficient though.